# Is there is any workaround for the dashboard 3 filter limitation?

Tags: configuration, dashboard

I know we can only add 3 filters to a dashboard but is there is any workaround to put more than 3  filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current limit is 3 and as of today, it is fixed. The only thing that can be increased today would be the Filter options, which by default are 10 and can be increased to about 50.

I invite you to vote on the idea in our ideas portal, in order that our developers take it into consideration in the next releases:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jM83AAE

Answer (score 0):

You could write a formula field that returns TRUE if multiple conditions are met, then use that formula in multiple reports shared by the dashboard. Then you can essentially filter the dashboard by the formula equaling true or false which in a way is somewhat of a workaround.